# How do I change file permissions in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

In Ubuntu I want to change the file permissions of a whole folder and all its sub folders to read/write by anybody

I have tried `sudo chmod 666 /var/www and sudo chmod 755 /var/www` without success

update

I have since found that changing privileges can also be done in the GUI by opening nautilus as sudo.

Answer (score 99):

So that you don't mess up other permissions already on the file, use the flag `+`, such as via

`sudo chmod -R o+rw /var/www`

Answer (score 19):

If you just want to change file permissions, you want to be careful about using `-R` on `chmod` since it will change anything, files or folders. If you are doing a *relative* change (like adding write permission for everyone), you can do this:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w /var/www
```

But if you want to use the literal permissions of read/write, you may want to select files versus folders:

```
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
```

(Which, by the way, for security reasons, I wouldn't recommend either of these.)

Or for folders:

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: Or `sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod o+rw {} \;` but it's still a terrible idea security wise.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes that would be preferred for changing permissions to `o+rw` on just files. And I agree about the security!

Comment: Good call on separating between files/folders.  I assumed that he wanted the 'other' user to be able to write files into each dir, but that might not be the case.

Answer (score -4):

Add `-R` for recursive:

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /var/www
```

Comment: Incorrect.  This will overwrite anything he had set on user/group and set it to rw.  This will break `cd`-ing into directories.

Comment: Yo man.. don't use "/"+sudo at anytime. Once I have destroyed a whole server running 10 websites by changing permission for whole directory. Give the folder name appropriately.