# Create a folder only readable by me

Tags: linux

I'm using a remote server via ssh. The problem is that all users can read and copy my user folder /export/home/yemino  and its sub folders, and also I can read and copy their files (this last is not a problem).

I'm just an user (i.e. I haven't root privileges). And I want to have a work folder, for example /export/home/yemino/work only readable by my (and admin, of course) with my "secret" C codes.

What ways you know to do this?

Comment: Man chmod.  Type that in to the shell and read it

Comment: google for `chmod`and if you still have trouble solving your problem with this command ask on superuser or a different site because SO is about programming

Comment: @EdHeal Did you become a victim of auto correct ? ;-)

Comment: Bloody predictive text on this phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change file permissions in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251963/how-do-i-change-file-permissions-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a directory with the [mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) command and afterwards you can use [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) to change the rights of other users to that folder.

You can do something like this:

```
mkdir testing 
chmod -R 700 testing
```